# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, service, outlook-2010

I have created windows service in .Net 4.5.Service is written to open outlook client,
read emails from Inbox folder, downloads attachments.The code written is correct,
since I have run & tested it in console application project.
But when I install the web service using "installutil" and run it,
the service throws following error on following line of code:

```
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
```

Error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due
>   to the following error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)).

FYI, the service is not running on my machine,I feel that service might require some permission, if so please let me know how to assign permissions to windows service.

Comment: The answer is not to run Outlook from a service, its not supposed to be used that way. For a start MAPI profiles are bound to the currently logged on user not the account under which the service is running and even if you got around this MAPI is exclusive so the service would stop the user being able to logon to their own profile on their desktop.

Comment: Code here :-  Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                ns = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Comment: Error :- Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
failed due to the following error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

Use a low-level API instead - Extended MAPI. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API (for example, Redemption).